# I need 'python-support' on a Mac. Where can I find it?

Tags: python, macos

If I am on a debian based system and using python and I want to update some modules, there is a feature of python called 'python-support'. I can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install python-support
```

I can't manage to find it anywhere for mac, and I have attempted to install it using mac ports via the ...

```
sudo port install python-support
```

... command. I can't seem to find it anywhere on the web.

In Debian the equivalent of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
update-python-modules <module-name>
```

There are two answers that would help. Either

1. How could I install python-support on Mac / where to find it?
2. What is an equivalent command to update-python-modules ?

Many thanks in advance. And yes, I have Googled extensively :-)

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support Why would you need this on a Mac?  What would it do for you?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu package. Rather unlikely it will run on Mac. Which feature(s) do you need? Probably there are other existing packages that could meet your requirements...

Comment: @DerekLitz It would help me to easily update a module when the version I have is out of date. Do you know of an alternative way?

Comment: I don't think it does what you think it does...

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Really? What does update-python-modules do then? EDIT: Ahh, I see, rebuilds the byte code as per answer below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update-python-modules` does not update the modules to their latest version. It rebuilds the byte code for the existing modules and is intended to be used after upgrading Python to a new version. There's a similar script named `python-updater` in Gentoo.

I doubt you have any reason to have it on a Mac; Python versions usually only change with OS updates, and those clean out your `site-packages`. If you really need this exact functionality, you can use `find` like so:

```
find {,/Users/*}/Library/Python/*/ -name '*.py[co]' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks for deciphering it, despite the vagueness of the question! If you are interested to know why, in the current version of web2py when you run it for the first time it gets an import error and says there is no module named 'gluon.widget' The developers recommended a temp bug fix by running update-python-modules in Debian.

Comment: Next time, put that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Mac user or developer, but refer to http://www.fprimex.com/coding/pymac.html, you can use `easy_install` or `pip` utility as they are on Windows or Linux.

For example:

Install a module:

```
pip install <module>
```

Upgrade a module:

```
pip install <module> -U
```

Comment: The package managers available for Mac can help manage some python modules as well.  (ie. Mac Ports, try "port info py-cherrypy3").

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade all your installed packages (using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)):

`pip freeze --local | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs echo pip install -U`

Answer (score -2):

I believe python supports all OS like Windows, Ubuntu, Mac etc
Please refer http://python.org/download/

Comment: The poster is asking a question about a feature that can be found in a package called "python-support", and how he can get similar functionality on Mac.